# Swift: can I make drop down menu stay clickable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, drop-down-menu, overflow

I am using a drop down menu in my project which is located inside a tableview. So far I have been able to make it overflow properly by making its cells zPosistion higher than the others

```
cell.layer.zPosition = 3
```

And make it clickable with the following code

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with e: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let result = super.hitTest(point, with:e) {
        return result
    }
    for sub in self.subviews.reversed() {
        let pt = self.convert(point, to:sub)
        if let result = sub.hitTest(pt, with:e) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This all works fine, but when I start scrolling in the tableview, the last part (the one that makes the drop down clickable) stops work, and when you try to click the drop down part that overflows, the click goes right trough to the cell below. Does anyone know a way to fix this? I know the way I am making this drop down is not optimal, but I would really like to make it work. This a link to part of my project where you can see the problem in action

https://github.com/Rawchris/Drop-down-overflow3

I hope you are able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are proposing a view inside a tableview cell that "spills out" when expanded. This is problematic because it works against the framework. Smells of this are having to go all the way down to hit testing or overriding `didMoveToSuperview`. I don't know how I could make it work in such a way. Even if I could, I wouldn't recommend it. There is a lot of built-in behaviour in UIKit and going against the framework is almost never a good idea: what about landscape orientation? Size classes? Dynamic text? What works in a release will easily break in another release.

Instead, I propose a solution based on common system elements: Auto Layout and view hierarchy.

Take a look at this scheme:
[image]

On the left is your original approach. When inspecting the view hierarchy one can see that the view is nested inside a table view cell. When "spilling over" the cell, then we are out of support from the system, because everything in table views is organized around cells and their defined size. That causes the problem of expanded buttons to not be interactive outside of the boundaries of the cell.

On the right there is my suggestion. I have lifted the button at the same level of the table view, alongside it, in the view controller. Now, when expanding the button, all options work. Then to create the illusion of the button being pinned to the cell, I just modify the top constraint dynamically, informed by the scrollview offset (a tableview is a scrollview after all).

This has implications of course. If you want to affect the cell with the selected option, typically you would need to reload the tableview with the new configuration (or at least, the affected cell). If you want to keep several buttons over several cells, then it gets tricky to calculate the constraints (though it can be done knowing the cell height via the tableviewDelegate). If you want to add a navigation bar, then the offset will need some tweaking. All in all, we are considering a non-standard UI element that needs some custom work to make it look right, so some effort is due. In any case, I recommend to base the solution in standard solutions in UIKit.